# duty cycle execution periods using timers

Tags: android

i need to do duty cycle function to run tow operations using timers in cascade during certain periods such that during ON period (x sec) which runs operation 1 using timer1 and when timer 1 finished then followed by the second off period (y sec) which runs operation 2 using timer2 and repeats the scenario again and soon.
i'm beginner programmer

please can any one help me to run properly.

i tried to write the below code and its looks like:

```
 package com.example.periodictimer;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Timer t1 = new Timer();
Timer t2 = new Timer();
TimerTask mTimerTask1;
TimerTask mTimerTask2;
TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
boolean z;
Handler hand = new Handler();
Handler hand1 = new Handler();
Button hButtonStart;
int time =0;
int time1 =0;
boolean flag1;
```

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

doTimerTask1();
```

}
public void doTimerTask1(){

```
mTimerTask1 = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        hand.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                time++;
                tv1.setText("Execute Operation1: " + time);
                doTimerTask2();
            }
        });

    }
    };

    // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
    t1.schedule(mTimerTask1,0, 3000);  //
```

}

public void doTimerTask2(){

```
mTimerTask1 = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        hand.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                time1++;
                // update TextView
                tv2.setText("Execute Operation2:" + time1);

                //Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
            }
        });
    }};

    // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
    t1.schedule(mTimerTask2,500, 5000);  //
```

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use two timers and the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method instead of the `schedule` method.

This methods works as follow `scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, delay, period)`

where :
**TimerTask**: the task to be executed an instance of `TimerTask` class. here you can turn your flag On in one of the timer tasks and turn it off in the other.

**delay** : the amount of delay before running the task for the first time.

**period**: the duty cycle period before the consecutive executions of the timer task.

The trick is to schedule two timers with the same delay cycle period, but one of them starts with 0 delay where the other starts with the delay = ON_period.

The code sample below shows it in a java program where a flag is turned on for 4 seconds then turned off for two seconds and so on.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class TestTimer {
    TimerTask timerTask2;
    TimerTask timerTask1;
    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    Timer t2 = new Timer();

    boolean flag = true;
    private Date date;
    private DateFormat  dateFormat;

    public TestTimer() {
        flag = true;
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");;
    }

    public void test() {
        timerTask1 = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                flag = true;
                date = new Date();
                System.out.println("Task1  [" + (flag ? "ON" : "OFF" ) + "] " +
                dateFormat.format(date));
            }
        };

        timerTask2 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                flag = false;
                date = new Date();
                System.out.println("Task2  [" + (flag ? "ON" : "OFF" ) + "] " +
                        dateFormat.format(date));
            }
        };



        t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask1, 0, 6000);
        t2.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, 4000, 6000);



    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {


        TestTimer tt = new TestTimer();
        tt.test();

    }
}
```